# Can I upload an iOS app from OS X running on a VM to the App Store?

Tags: macos, ios-appstore, virtualization

I don't have an Apple device and I need to create a iOS app. I was wondering if I could do it from a VM running OSX. I know that you can do this for testing, but can I upload the final version to the App Store?

Comment: Note that running a virtualized OSX outside Apple hardware is against the OSX EULA. It allows you "[...] to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software
within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is
already running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software development; (b) testing during
software development; (c) using OS X Server; or (d) personal, non-commercial use." Source: [Software License Agreement For OS X Yosemite](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX10103.pdf)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hackintosh

Comment: [Hackintosh isn't off-topic here](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-ask-different) unless it relates directly to custom/specific hardware, which this question doesn't. Voting to leave open.

Comment: So, just to clarify, is it still illegal if I go ahead and purchase a official license?

Comment: Please don't ask different things within the same question, it makes answering (and accepting one answer) rather difficult. It's best to ask a new question in such situations (maybe with a link to the original one if context is required).

Comment: But to spare you the effort of a new question: The OS X license agreement (see topmost comment) forbids the installation/running of OS X on non-Apple hardware (which includes installation in a VM running on non-Apple hardware). AFAIK the only way to buy a license actually is to buy a Mac anyway.

Comment: @patrix, thanks for the clarification. Regarding the license, I can see them being sold on the Apple Store (Not relevant now I guess)

Comment: As alternative, you can develop your iOS app in the virtual machine then, use this https://www.macincloud.com/ to deploy it to appstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. In Xcode, you can set archive for iOS Device even if you haven't got an iOS Device (this is instead of "Simulator") and upload this binary to iTunes Connect perfectly fine.

Comment: I think this answers the question about the possibility. Too bad its not legal though.